# HashMap ошибка в коде

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Я сейчас изучаю HashMap. Моя проблема в том, что не могу объявить класс, вылезает непонятная ошибка.

```
public class Teach {
class HashMap<K,V>

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

}
```

Притом, строка `class HashMap<K,V>` работает, но всегда, ниже стоящая строка подчеркивается красным. А строка с объявлением вообще не работает. В чем проблема?

`Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Comment: Покажите непонятную ошибку.

Comment: Для чего в классе `Teach` класс `HashMap`?

Comment: Вы создаете класс HashMap перекрывая родительский и потом внутири статического метода пытаетесь получить его инстанс. А так делать нельзя. Переименуйте просто свой клас HashMap в другой

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Teach {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
}
```